# Pass commandline argument to browser with Protractor

Tags: phantomjs, protractor

I'm trying to get PhantomJS working with Protractor. I'm currently having an issue with Phantom, but not Chrome, when my code needs to reach a backend endpoint which is kept on a separate server. As such, I would like to test it with the `--ignore-ssl-errors` option.

Unfortunately, the [example config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) file provided in the Protractor documentation doesn't seem to list any way to pass arguments to the browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer was in a closed Protractor issue: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/150

You CAN pass arguments to the browser with the `phantomjs.cli.args` property, which takes an array of arguments. Just add it to the `capabilities` property in your configuration, in he same location where you specify the `browserName`:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'phantomjs',
  'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs').path,
  'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--web-security=false', '--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--webdriver-loglevel=DEBUG'],
}
```